# Image stored in FileList not showing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I was working on a file upload in React, storing the file in FileList and showing a preview. The image seems to be stored correctly but it does not render and the `alt` text keeps getting displayed.

`this.props.file` contains something like this: `file: "blob:http://localhost:3000/1d648245-4447-41a4-b11e-a5a7b385bb9b"`

The code of the upload component is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import './Upload.css';
import { setFile } from '../../actions/imagefile';

class Upload extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    history: PropTypes.object,
    setFile: PropTypes.func,
    file: PropTypes.object,
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.props.setFile({
      file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]),
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <img src={this.props.file} alt="reviewed img" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  file: state.imageFile.file,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setFile,
})(Upload);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this.props.file contains something like this: `file: "blob:http://localhost:3000/1d648245-4447-41a4-b11e-a5a7b385bb9b"`.

From this I'm deducing that `this.props.file` is an object with structure

```
{
  file: "blob:http://localhost:3000/1d648245-4447-41a4-b11e-a5a7b385bb9b"
}
```

And your `propTypes` definition also says `props.file` is an object

```
file: PropTypes.object
```

So you should change your code to

```
<img src={this.props.file.file} alt="reviewed img" />
```

Checkout the link:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ubtvsc?file=Upload.js

**But, you should refactor your code to avoid this unnecessary nesting.**